# Сравнение элементов двух массивов

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

У меня есть 2 np.array массива, оба состоят из 0 и 1. Нужно их сравнить и посчитать количество несоответствий. Пробовал сделать таким образом:

```
unique, counts = np.unique(X2==X3, return_counts=True)
print(dict(zip(unique, counts)))
```

Но в результате выдает около 300млн значений true и false, хотя длина обоих 25000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы посчитать количество несоответствий соответствующих элементов двух 1D Numpy векторов:

```
(X2 != X3).sum()
```

Пример:

```
In [42]: X2 = np.array([0,0,1,1,0,0])

In [43]: X3 = np.array([1,0,0,1,0,0])

In [44]: X2 != X3
Out[44]: array([ True, False,  True, False, False, False])

# индексы несовпадающих значений
In [45]: np.where(X2 != X3)
Out[45]: (array([0, 2], dtype=int64),)

# количество несоответствий
In [46]: (X2 != X3).sum()
Out[46]: 2
```

Comment: Cпасибо, а порядковые номера неверных значений можно вывести?

Comment: @Midnight, добавил пример...